# Do the .rb files in your db >>migrate have to be the same name as the rb files in your model folder?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I am fresh into Sinatra and Activerecord and I noticed I get a lot of errors such as

```
 LoadError: cannot load such file -- ./model/character_houses
```

or

```
 rake aborted!
 NameError: uninitialized constant House
```

The first one is when I try to load into irb with require './app' for my main rb file.

The second is when I try to load a seed file.

Could someone just explain how file structures should be linked when using Sinatra and ActiveRecord. I have no problem setting the files up it's only when I try to check within irb or actually fill the tables.

A lot of the forums I see online pertain mostly to ruby on rails but we as a class are starting that after this so I am not sure if it is similar or relevant to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

With sinatra the 'require' order is important

```
Dir.glob('./app/{exceptions,helpers}/*.rb').each do |file|
require file
end

require './app/controllers/api_controller'
require './app/uploaders/application_uploader'

Dir.glob('./app/{uploaders,jobs,controllers,models,etls,docs}/*.rb').each do |file|
  require file
end
```

try 'require_relative app' with irb